# Installing with MSI in a web page - does not add app to Add/Remove Programs list

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

I have an ASP.NET based page which uploads an MSI file and installs it on the server machine.

I am able to upload the MSI file and install it successfully. The MSI installs a Windows service and this service appears in the services manager. But this installation does NOT appear in the Add/Remove Programs. I did try impersonation but had the same result.
If this msi was executed in the command line or by double clicking on it, then it appears in the Add/Remove Programs.

I am running on IIS 7 and using a MSI developed using VS.NET 2008

Thanks in advance,
V

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably not installing for **all users**, and your IIS process is running under another user account...